# 'Sweep clause' in a contract: where does this name come from?

Tags: idioms, legalese

The expression is encountered in legal field with this approximate meaning: a clause which is broad and vague enough to extend obligations to unspecified ones.

I read that the expression comes from "to sweep in", but can't really grab the meaning of  "sweep in" in this context.

[This page](http://searchcio.techtarget.com/news/1277518/Smart-IT-outsourcing-advice-in-a-declining-market) explains the use of a sweep clause.

Comment: I am not a lawyer and am not familiar with the legal concept of a "*sweep clause*", so I'll present this as a comment, instead of an answer. The [adjective *sweeping*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sweeping) means "*wide in range or effect*", derived from a [usage which dates back to the 14th c.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sweep), of "*to collect by sweeping*", ultimately derived from the act of *sweeping* as with a broom (picture using a broom and dustpan to collect all the detritus on your floor). This also led to the term "*sweepstakes*".

Comment: http://www.insidecounsel.com/2010/12/31/technology-outsourcing-transactions---strategies-t

Both meanings seem to be encompassed, a clause that is "wide range in effect" and one that attempts to "sweep up like a broom" disputes which are not clearly articulated in the other clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the fashion that it is used in the terms *Sweep Clause* or *Sweeping Clause* it implies that the clause will "sweep in" or "collect" any items that may have otherwise been missed; ergo the sweeping clause is "a clause wide in range or effect that collects what might otherwise be missed."

Thanks to Dan Bron, we also have the origin: it came from the act of sweeping as with a broom, which grew into the "to collect by sweeping" definition which is also now used in games and contests to denote an overwhelming or complete victory (such as when you hear an announcer claim that an athlete has "swept the board"). See [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sweeping) and [here](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sweep) for Dan Bron's references.

It is important to note, however, that the term *Sweep Clause* in and of itself isn't anything more than a description for a type of clause (such as Noninterference, Jurisdiction, Severability, etc.). It is the legal language ***contained within*** the clause that give it the power to "catch items that may have fallen through the cracks," not its name.

Comment: I'd agree with the "Sweeping a broom" analogy, and was about to reply with similar. The implication is that by sweeping a broom along a floor, you catch everything in one go without having to pick up individual pieces.